# Android GPS Manifest not work 

Tags: android, gps, android-manifest

I have used the debug mode , under ActivityThread Perform Source not found.
 I have also added FINE LOCATION UNDER ..

```
<android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

how about adding .. to the location , like ..

```
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> 
<android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Where should be added ?

here is the activity for GPS

```
<activity android:name="com.easyTravel.tool_gpsMap.tool_gpsMap"></activity>
```

Comment: Hi! You can format your code by putting 4 spaces at the beginning of each line *(the `{}` button on top of the editor does just that)* -- I've tried to do it for you *(except there were some missing XML tags, I'd say -- maybe you'll need to edit your question to fix it)*, this time :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These permissions should be added outside the application tag but the user-library will be inside the application tag.
See the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.live"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">

      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>



    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".FirstAcivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           <!-- other activities here -->

 </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

</manifest>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If I have many activities to run,
should user-library run added before the activity only used for GPS or the first activity which the user-library is not required?

Comment: User-library is added only once , no matter which activity is using GPS.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to add it in the manifest
beneth the  tag

```
 </application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
```